# iOS delegate Does not get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, delegation

I'm having strange problem, trying to call my delegate - it never gets called. As i understand ,delegate never gets set. i'm using ARC.

CueCreateDelegate.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class CueCreateDelegate;
@protocol CueCreDelegate <NSObject>
    - (void)CueCreatedCall;
@end

@interface CueCreateDelegate : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <CueCreDelegate> delegate;

-(void)CueCreated;
- (void) setdelegate:(id<CueCreDelegate>) delegates; //for testing
@end
```

CueCreateDelegate.m
CueCreated is called from another class and it prints the bad news...

```
#import "CueCreateDelegate.h"

@implementation CueCreateDelegate
@synthesize delegate ;

- (void) setdelegate:(id<CueCreDelegate>) delegates{
        delegate = delegates;
}

-(void)CueCreated{
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(CueCreatedCall)]) {
        [delegate CueCreatedCall];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Delegate method not getting called...%@",delegate);
    }

}
@end
```

MatrixViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CueCreateDelegate.h"

@interface MatrixViewController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,CueCreDelegate>{
    CueCreateDelegate *cueCre;
}
```

MatrixViewController.m
CueCreatedCall is never called..

```
-(void)CueCreatedCall{
    NSLog(@"lsakdlakjdlks");
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

  cueCre = [[CueCreateDelegate alloc] init];

   // [cueCre setdelegate:self];
    [cueCre setDelegate:self];
    NSLog(@"%@",[cueCre delegate]);

}
```

Comment: Overall your code looks like it should work.  Although I don't understand why you have that testing method.  It just seems like an extra step which can complicate the code.  Why not just assign the delegate normally?

Comment: Well, as you can see i'm assigning it normally. Test method was to test if delegate gets called.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is the `viewDidLoad` method called in `MatrixViewController`? If so, what is the output of the `NSLog` and is `cueCre` `nil` or not? As a side note - with ARC you should use `weak`, not `assign` for delegate properties. Also, there is no need for the `@synthesize` lines anymore. Method names should always start with a lower case letter. And use the property if you create it. The implementation of the `CueCreated` method should use `self.delegate`, not `delegate`.

Comment: It looks like CueCreated is never called. Are you calling it from somewhere? Also setdelegate will never be called, I don't understand what you think that method is doing.

Comment: Where are you calling CueCreated method ? And also, shouldn't the delegate property be set as a weak property instead of an assign property in CueCreateDelegate?

Comment: @rdelmar Good eye. It should be `setDelegate:`, not `setdelegate:`. It appears that method was added to help debug why the delegate isn't being set. But the OP just made it worse and more confusing by overriding the method with the wrong name.

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing with "setdelegate" method. please ignore it(as you can see it was commented).  CueCreated is called from another class. NSLog with cueCre prints -> <MatrixViewController: 0x713b4b0>

Comment: I have changed from delegate to self.delegate in CueCreated and from assing to weak - delegate still is not  being called.

Comment: Note that methods should start with lowercase letters.   And methods should be camel cased.   I.e. `setDelegate:` not `setdelegate:`.

Comment: Then the problem is in the code where you call CueCreated, which doesn't gets executed or it doesn't enter some scope that you expect to be executed.

Comment: @HarizHent If the log statement in `viewDidLoad` is printing what you stated, then the delegate is set. So what's the problem then? The log statement proves that the delegate is in fact being set.

Comment: The problem is that method "CueCreatedCall" never gets called.